# Column Headers are conjoined instead of separated, but the columns have correct corresponding Data

Tags: r

[PROOF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IjBKO.png) The column has correct data but the headers are clearly incorrect and need to be organized in a way so each column has its own unique header.

I tried to use the following code to organize the data.

```
write.csv = separate_wider_delim(df, 1, delim = ";", names_sep = "_")
```

But as you can see the headers are still not in order. Thats the only problem. It needs to be so each column has its own unique header. For example, it should just be **Age** above a number like 58 instead of age.job.marital.education.default.balance which basically adds everything and anything together which is not good.

Below is the link for the data set so you can get extra reference if needed.

It would be great if you could help. Thanks!

https://github.com/yipyipperton/data-set-/blob/196a6984e1e4bd4126a9de35b43e8a150568dfd2/bank.csv

Comment: How did you import the data? `read.csv` or `readr::read_csv2`?

Comment: Why are you overwriting the name of a built-in function (`write.csv`) with the output of a different function (`separate_wider_delim`)? What is the shape of `df` before you try to do this?